# What do you call that stop-frame ghost technology?

Tags: software, video, onion-skinning

When doing stop-frame animation with a video camera, some software has the ability to overlay the photo you're about to take with a semi-transparent ghost of the previous photo, allowing you to line up your shot perfectly.

What is this technology called?

Comment: Not sure if this is technically a photography question, but this was the only place I could find to ask it.

Comment: Also useful for panoramic shots. I'm not aware of any dSLRs which do this (in live view or otherwise), but some point-and-shoot cameras do. (In panorama-mode... A stop-motion mode would be cool too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Onion skinning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_skinning) I think.