# how to have a ghost of previous photo on screen when taking a new photo?

Tags: dslr, stop-motion, onion-skinning

I'm an art student and I'm working on a stop motion short video that I'm making and it would help a lot if a ghost like view of my previous frame that i took to show on the lcd of my camera when I'm taking the next frame on top of the live view , so i can change the composition with having the previous frame and live view at the same time.
i want to know if there is such a feature for sony a7rii camera or what camera has such feature.
thanks.

Comment: Hi omgtheykilledkenny and welcome to Photo.SE! On this site (and on the internet in general) it is encouraged to do some research before asking questions. If you would've [searched for "ghost image"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=ghost+image) you would've found the duplicate yourself.
Additionally, it is expected to provide as much information as possible in the question, to enable other visitors to answer appropriately. For example: you do not mention which camera you have. If it's not a Canon, your questions would be no longer a duplicate and would be great on its own!

Comment: If you are doing stop motion photography there is software designed for this (that would run on a tethered computer). The feature name you are looking for is normally called "onion skinning" and can often be used to display more than just the last frame taken. Not set as an answer, as you specified in-camera solution, but this is a popular way to handle stop-motion photography.

Comment: Related: [What do you call that stop-frame ghost technology?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3222/what-do-you-call-that-stop-frame-ghost-technology/3229#3229)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke In all fairness to the OP, 'ghost+image' pulls up a lot of results that have nothing to do with "onion Skinning" when shooting stop motion photography.

Comment: ok sorry guys , i mentioned my camera